# how can I make a view animate along a specific path?

Tags: android, animation

Here is the method I want to use to implement my require.

```
    /**
 * Constructs and returns an ObjectAnimator that animates the target using a multi-float setter
 * along the given <code>Path</code>. A <code>Path</code></> animation moves in two dimensions,
 * animating coordinates <code>(x, y)</code> together to follow the line. In this variation, the
 * coordinates are float x and y coordinates used in the first and second parameter of the
 * setter, respectively.
 *
 * @param target The object whose property is to be animated. This object may
 * have a public method on it called <code>setName()</code>, where <code>name</code> is
 * the value of the <code>propertyName</code> parameter. <code>propertyName</code> may also
 * be the case-sensitive complete name of the public setter method.
 * @param propertyName The name of the property being animated or the name of the setter method.
 * @param path The <code>Path</code> to animate values along.
 * @return An ObjectAnimator object that is set up to animate along <code>path</code>.
 */
public static ObjectAnimator ofMultiFloat(Object target, String propertyName, Path path) {
    PropertyValuesHolder pvh = PropertyValuesHolder.ofMultiFloat(propertyName, path);
    return ofPropertyValuesHolder(target, pvh);
}
```

But what confuse me is that the Path is two dimension, and the value it return are a point (two dimension too), so what value should a pass to the  parameter propertyName?

this is my code, but I know the value I pass must be wrong.

```
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.rQuadTo(controlX, controlY, destinationX, destinationY);
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofMultiFloat(view, "translationX", mPath);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(5000);
        objectAnimator.start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator#ofFloat(Object target, String xPropertyName, String yPropertyName, Path path)`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need. I didn't watch the API carefully.